# what does anonymous function inside parameters means?

Tags: javascript

What does below code mean.As for as i understand. if there is variable `$wnd.document.bg_instance` , than call the function named `bg_instance`. But What is function inside function ? `function(a){b=a}` ?

Can Some one explain the flow of below code.

```
if($wnd.document.bg_instance){
$wnd.document.bg_instance.invoke(function(a){b=a});
$wnd.document.bg_instance=null
}
```

full function

```
   function rA() {
        var b = 'js_disabled';
        if ($wnd.document.bg_instance) {
            $wnd.document.bg_instance.invoke(function(a) {
                b = a
            });
            $wnd.document.bg_instance = null
        }
        return b
    }

return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is invoke in javascript

`invoke` is not a standard JavaScript function. It must be a method on the object provided by some other code in the program. What exactly it does will depend on how it is defined.

> What is function inside function ? `function(a){b=a}`

That is an argument that is passed to the function stored in the `invoke` property.

See this example of passing objects around:

```js
function myFunction(myArgument) {
    myArgument(3);  
}

myFunction(function (foo) { alert(foo + 1); });
```